# Scrubbing timeline of movieclip that executes actionscript within

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an as3 script that will scrub the timeline of a movieclip on the stage.
This scrubs the timeline and displays the frame by frame animation but does not execute any actionscript placed on key frames within that movieclip. Users can scrub backwards or forward. I would like to load the script as well as unload depending on the direction the user scrubs. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to call action script inside another movie clip that is on timline?

Comment: Yes. I have actionscript placed several times along the timeline that I would to execute as the scrubber moves thru the movieclips timeline.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to make new class and extend MovieClip, Inside of that class you can create public methods that you can call from timeline:

```
public class MyMC extends MovieClip {
    public function myMC() {
        // constructor
    }

    public function load():void{
        // Do something
    }

    public function unload():void{
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Than if you used "interface" to to add movie clip, click on movie clip and change instance from `MovieClip` to your class `MyMC`. Give it also a name (variable name) for example `my_mc` Than you can call your function from action on timeline

```
my_mc.load();
my_mc.unload();
```

Or if you are using just actions to create movie clip you can do like this:

```
var my_mc:MyMC = new MyMC();
my_mc.load();
my_mc.unload();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look onto this method. Has anyone used addframescript? It looks like it could work.